# Call a non-default constructor for a concept

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection, c++20, c++-concepts

I am making a dependency injection system via static polymorphism with C++20 concepts, so I have this example

I have an interface contract for a `Logger`:

```
template <typename TLogger>
concept ILogger = requires(TLogger engine) {
    { engine.LogInfo(std::declval<std::string>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { engine.LogError(std::declval<int>(), std::declval<std::string>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

A particular implementation of that interface with 2 ctors, a default and a non-default:

```
class MyLoggerImplementation
{
public:
    MyLoggerImplementation() : x(0)
    {

    }

    MyLoggerImplementation(int code) //non default constructor
    {
        x = code;
    }

    //Interface methods
public:
    void LogInfo(std::string errorMessage)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Info:  {}!\n", errorMessage);
    }

    void LogError(int errorCode, std::string errorMessage)
    {
        std::cout << std::format("Error:  {}! with code: {}\n", errorMessage, errorCode);
    }

    // private members
private:
    int x;
};
```

Then my `DatabaseAccessor` has a dependency to a `Logger`:

```
template<ILogger Logger>
class DatabaseAccessor
{
public:
    DatabaseAccessor() { }

public:
    bool QueryAll()
    {
        logger.LogInfo("querying all data");

        //...
        return true;
    }

    // Injected services
private:
    Logger logger;
};
```

And then when I try to instantiate a `DatabaseAccessor` and I inject the `Logger` dependency with `MyLoggerImplementation` it will call the default constructor:

```
int main()
{
    DatabaseAccessor<MyLoggerImplementation> db; // this will instantiate with the default constructor

    // DatabaseAccessor<MyLoggerImplementation(10)> db; // ???
    db.QueryAll();
}
```

How can I instantiate `MyLoggerImplementation` with that non-default constructor?

Comment: You're doing an awful lot of `declval` in a requires expression, when you could just list them as "parameters" and it would be tons more readable. Basically, if you're using `declval` in a concept, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: "*this will instantiate with the default constructor*" That doesn't instantiate it with a "constructor"; you're just passing a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an instance of the logger as a parameter:

```cpp
template <ILogger L>
class DatabaseAccessor
{
    L logger;

public:
    explicit DatabaseAccessor(L logger) : logger(std::move(logger)) { }
};
```

If you need something more involved than this (like your logger isn't move-constructible), then instead of taking an `L` you take a function that returns an `L`:

```cpp
template <class F, class T>
concept FactoryFor = std::invocable<F> and std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<F>, T>;

template <ILogger L>
class DatabaseAccessor
{
    L logger;
public:
    template <FactoryFor<L> F>
    explicit DatabaseAccessor(F factory) : logger(f()) { }
};
```

This approach has advantages over just forwarding arguments into the logger:

- it works just fine when you add another member you need to initialize
- it allows for using braced-init-lists to initialize the logger
- it's clearer on the call-site (consider `DatabaseAccessor<OstreamLogger> da(std::cout);` - what's the accessor doing with `cout` vs `DatabaseAccessor da(OstreamLogger(std::cout));`)

---

Note that this:

```cpp
template <typename TLogger>
concept ILogger = requires(TLogger engine) {
    { engine.LogInfo(std::declval<std::string>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { engine.LogError(std::declval<int>(), std::declval<std::string>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

could really be:

```cpp
template <typename TLogger>
concept ILogger = requires (TLogger engine, int i, std::string s) {
    { engine.LogInfo(s) } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { engine.LogError(i, s) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

The two aren't exactly identical (I'm passing in lvalues while you're passing in rvalues), but I doubt that distinction will matter in your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass the required parameters to the `DatabaseAccessor` constructor, so its initializer list can then pass the parameters to the `Logger`'s constructor, eg:

```cpp
template<ILogger Logger>
class DatabaseAccessor
{
public:
    template<typename... Params>
    DatabaseAccessor(Params&&... params) : logger(std::forward<Params>(params)...) { }
    ...
private:
    Logger logger;
};
```

```
DatabaseAccessor<MyLoggerImplementation> db(12345);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a forwarding constructor to `DatabaseAccessor` that will pass on the parameters to construct the wrapped log object.  That would look like

```
template<ILogger Logger>
class DatabaseAccessor
{
public:
    DatabaseAccessor() { }
    template <typename... Ts, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Logger, Ts...>, bool> = true>
    DatabaseAccessor(Ts&&... ts) : logger(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) { }

public:
    bool QueryAll()
    {
        logger.LogInfo("querying all data");

        //...
        return true;
    }

    // Injected services
private:
    Logger logger;
};

DatabaseAccessor<MyLoggerImplementation> db(10);
```

The `std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Logger, Ts...>, bool> = true` part is a [SFINAE technique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) that only allows this constructor to be called if the `Logger` type can be constructed by the passed in parameters.  This is needed as otherwise this template could be called when you want a copy or move to happen instead.

Comment: This is [tag:c++20], so `requires std::constructible_from<Logger, Ts...>`